Plotting a mesh with transparent nans doesn't seem to work
The following code:
import pyvista as pv
import numpy as np

def test_pyvista_layers():
    """Test how PyVista handles multiple mesh layers with NaN values and opacity settings"""
    
    # Create a simple sphere
    sphere = pv.Sphere(radius=1.0)
    total_points = sphere.n_points
    
    # Create three meshes with known patterns
    mesh1 = sphere.copy()
    mesh2 = sphere.copy()
    mesh3 = sphere.copy()
    
    # Test 1: Basic overlap with different values and NaN
    values1 = np.full(total_points, np.nan)  # Initialize with NaN
    values1[:total_points//3] = 1  # Set first third to 1
    
    values2 = np.full(total_points, np.nan)  # Initialize with NaN
    values2[total_points//3:2*total_points//3] = 2  # Set middle third to 2
    
    values3 = np.full(total_points, np.nan)  # Initialize with NaN
    values3[2*total_points//3:] = 3  # Set final third to 3
    
    # Validate NaN counts and non-overlap
    nan_count1 = np.sum(np.isnan(values1))
    nan_count2 = np.sum(np.isnan(values2))
    nan_count3 = np.sum(np.isnan(values3))
    
    print(f"\nNaN Counts:")
    print(f"Layer 1: {nan_count1} NaN values ({(nan_count1/total_points)*100:.1f}% of points)")
    print(f"Layer 2: {nan_count2} NaN values ({(nan_count2/total_points)*100:.1f}% of points)")
    print(f"Layer 3: {nan_count3} NaN values ({(nan_count3/total_points)*100:.1f}% of points)")
    
    # Check for overlap between non-NaN regions
    overlap_12 = np.sum(~np.isnan(values1) & ~np.isnan(values2))
    overlap_23 = np.sum(~np.isnan(values2) & ~np.isnan(values3))
    overlap_13 = np.sum(~np.isnan(values1) & ~np.isnan(values3))
    
    print("\nOverlap Check:")
    print(f"Overlap between layers 1-2: {overlap_12} points")
    print(f"Overlap between layers 2-3: {overlap_23} points")
    print(f"Overlap between layers 1-3: {overlap_13} points")
    
    # Validate complete coverage
    total_coverage = np.sum(~np.isnan(values1) | ~np.isnan(values2) | ~np.isnan(values3))
    print(f"\nTotal Coverage: {total_coverage} points ({(total_coverage/total_points)*100:.1f}% of surface)")
    
    plotter = pv.Plotter()
    
    # Add meshes with point data and NaN handling
    mesh1.point_data['values'] = values1
    mesh2.point_data['values'] = values2
    mesh3.point_data['values'] = values3
    
    # Add meshes with nan_opacity=0 to make NaN values completely transparent
    plotter.add_mesh(mesh1, color='red', opacity=1.0, label='Layer 1', nan_opacity=0.0)
    plotter.add_mesh(mesh2, color='blue', opacity=1.0, label='Layer 2', nan_opacity=0.0)
    plotter.add_mesh(mesh3, color='green', opacity=1.0, label='Layer 3', nan_opacity=0.0)
    
    return plotter

test_plotter = test_pyvista_layers()
test_plotter.show()

Generates the attached image (a green sphere) rather than the expected three part sphere. My understanding is that nan_opacity=0.0 should make the rest of the sphere transparent.

It also prints the following output, confirming that the points are, indeed, NaN.

NaN Counts: Layer 1: 562 NaN values (66.7% of points) Layer 2: 561 NaN
values (66.6% of points) Layer 3: 561 NaN values (66.6% of points)
Overlap Check: Overlap between layers 1-2: 0 points Overlap between
layers 2-3: 0 points Overlap between layers 1-3: 0 points
Total Coverage: 842 points (100.0% of surface)

I've tried many different ways to render this, and have scoured the documentation, but nothing works. Suggestions as to how to handle this appreciated!

The problem is that you are requesting specific colours for your meshes which overrides any scalars on each mesh, which in turn affects mapping (effectively disabling anything relying on scalars). You can try passing show_scalar_bar=True to add_mesh() and see that it doesn't do anything.
The simplest solution is to use a colormap that matches the colours you intended as categorical data:
cmap = ['red', 'blue', 'green']                                     
plotter.add_mesh(mesh1, label='Layer 1', nan_opacity=0.0, cmap=cmap)
plotter.add_mesh(mesh2, label='Layer 2', nan_opacity=0.0, cmap=cmap)
plotter.add_mesh(mesh3, label='Layer 3', nan_opacity=0.0, cmap=cmap)

Note that I've removed opacity=1.0 which is the default, and color=..., which allows the scalars on each mesh to manifest.
Here's the result:

The only weird thing is that the pieces are translucent now. I'm not sure why this happens. It seems to be a side-effect of the nan opacity, as changing that to 1.0 makes also the rest of the mesh opaque. Perhaps this is a bug. Might be worth asking on the issue tracker.
